# How to use find in mongoose

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a code, it should create mongoose.schema, save it, find it and check if its the same as the input. So i know i have an error but it wont log it in the console so i don't know whats the problem.

This is express node.js server, using mongoose and js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const model = require('.//models/schema');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/register', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/register.html');
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response){
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/login.html')
});

const listener = app.listen(3000, function() {
  let myURL = new URL(`localhost:${listener.address().port}/register`);
  console.log(myURL.href);
});

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost${listener.address().port}:/register`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true    
    });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/submit-data', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/login')
  let user = new model({
    all:{
    'login': req.body.login,
    'password': req.body.password,
    'gender': req.body.gender,
    'birthday': req.body.birthday
  }});
  user.save()
  console.log('Successfuly Updated the data')
});

app.post('/submit-login', (req, res) => {
  model.find({
  'all.login': req.body.login, 
  'all.password': req.body.password}, function (err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    if(!user){
      console.log('No such user')
    }
    console.log('Successfully logged in')
  });
});
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let schema = new Schema({
    all:{
    'login': String,
    'password': String,
    'gender': String,
    'birthday': String
  }});

module.exports = mongoose.model('allInfo', schema);
```

I expected it to log error if its incorrect or to log "Successfully logged in" but it wont log any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const existingUser = await model.findOne({all.login:req.body.login}) //use async in function definition
```

then check if `existingUser` is undefined or null with if statements.

If no user is found `return req.next()`

If found, we need to check password,

```
if(req.body.password === existingUser.password){
 //return successful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to double check the next code lines:

```
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost${listener.address().port}:/register`, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true    
    });
```

The colon to separate the listening port should go just after 'localhost'...